# Probability of event with repetition

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving

I have to solve the following problem:
If a company's computer network has 2000 computers and 12 of them are broken,if we randomly select
10 computers,what are the odds of finding at least two broken ones?

I have used binomial distribution since we have repetition (a pc can be selected twice) which
gives me a probability of P(X>=2)=0.00157
([https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/bin.html](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Embognar/applets/bin.html))

Is this a correct way of tackling it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your sampling is without replacement thus the correct answer is

$$\mathbb{P}[X\ge 2]=1-\mathbb{P}[X=0]-\mathbb{P}[X =1]=1-\frac{\binom{1988}{10}+\binom{12}{1}\binom{1988}{9}}{\binom{2000}{10}}\approx0.001447=0.14\%$$

To simplify the calculations, in this example you can use binomial finding, without a lot of calculations

$$\mathbb{P}[X \ge 2]=1-\left(\frac{1988}{2000}\right)^{10}-10\left(\frac{12}{2000}\right)\left(\frac{1988}{2000}\right)^{9}\approx0.00157=0.15\%$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I also have to calculate average and variance. Can I not use default binomial distribution E(X)=N*p and V(X)=N*p*(1-p)?

Comment: @TheExtraSpicyBeef : Yes you can, but you must observe that, being your sampling (reasonably) without replacement, expectation is anyway correct but variance is

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=Np(1-p)\frac{1990}{1999}$$

these results come from the hypergeometric distribution